# Templates for Mobile Site

Tags: templates, mobile

Is there any built-in method for displaying a different template based off of <strike>browser size</strike> device (i.e. mobile device detection)?

I've done some research and all I can find is a ton of plugins that do way more than I need them to. I essentially just need a way to add a /mobile directory to my theme, and display that theme for mobile users.

Comment: No, there is no way for php to know browser size.

Comment: See [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178392/31545)

Comment: Good information about the `wp_is_mobile()` function, but I'm not really looking to detect screen size. There are plenty of PHP mobile detects out there, I'm just looking for a way to integrate that with a mobile theme. I might be able to use `wp_is_mobile()` to figure something out.

Comment: I don't really understand, *based off of browser size* and *not really looking to detect screen size*. Why don't you just go with a responsive design. Otherwise you need to look into filters like `template_include` to switch templates according to mobile or desktop using the `wp_is_mobile()` condition

Comment: Sorry, I do so many responsive designs I didn't think about what I typed in the original post. I meant to say device, not browser size. I'd like to do a responsive design, but my client already has a mobile site build and just wants to re-purpose that for their WordPress blog. I think your suggestion should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding this to my head:

```
<?
if (wp_is_mobile()) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . "/mobile/index.php");
    return;
}
?>
```

And it worked out fine for my purposes.