# Reliable method to detect mobiles

Tags: theme-development, mobile

I'm running a WordPress site and wanna setup a mobile site based on it.

I've tried some plugins like Mobile Themes which allows me to implement a different theme for mobile. The problem is when I use memcached, the main theme and mobile theme is confusing very often(e.g. access the site by mobile but meet a main theme)

I'm considering another way to do this now. Use a PHP mobile detective script, and write the code in all theme template files(e.g. `header.php`) like:

```
if(is_mobile()) {
  // mobile theme code
} else {
  // main theme code
}
```

for this, I need only to maintain one theme. I've never tried this way, not sure if there is any problem, and I didn't think about how to handle the style.css yet.(There are some plugins allow me to use different style rules for mobile, but I've never tried)

Does anybody could provide some suggestions?

Comment: There is **no** reliable way to do this with php. `wp_is_mobile()` is a joke and very unreliable and **will** fail in many enviroments. CSS responsive design is your best option here and much more reliable than php in this case. For extra info, read [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178392/31545) I've done recently on something similar

Comment: [`wp_is_mobile()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) The codex says *it should not be used for themes*. There must be some reliability issues. You better off using css media queries.

Comment: @PieterGoosen @Sisir Thanks for reply! I will not consider responsive theme because of the limitation of design and my site is a little complex, including many modules which shouldn't appear on mobile(use `display:none` is not a solution). And I'm not talking about `wp_is_mobile()`, I found some PHP scripts or plugins can do the check. Do you have any idea about if they are reliable? Or is there a mobile theme plugin which can be compatible with Memcached, eAccelerator and W3 Total Cache?

Comment: All php scripts that handles device detection in unreliable and will fail. You will dish up wrong info to at least 10% of users, maybe even more.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Got it! So is there any way to detect device reliably?

Comment: No, as I have stated in the linked post, any method that uses client side based apps is unreliable as client side apps can be manipulated. And server side languages like php cannot detect client side apps because it runs too early

Comment: @PieterGoosen How about if I can provide a deferent url to the mobile users? e.g. sub domain `m.` or add a tail `?mobile=1`

Comment: How are you going to detect that mobile. That is not a problem, but you want reliability, which brings you back to exactly what you have asked in the main question ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen I can provide unique urls in some cases, e.g. provide a QRCode(only mobile can scan) and provide url in WeChat(mobile only app) which is the most important context, cooperate with the PHP detection. Do you think that can get a reasonable reliability?

Comment: This discussion is getting off topic now. In Wordpress there is `wp_is_mobile()` that you will not use. Any other script or platform that provides mobile detection has nothing to do with Wordpress as such. How reliable those scripts is, I don't know, the only thing I can tell you is, php in general **cannot** detect browsers or devices, any app written for php relies on client side info, not server side, so any app that detects mobiles in php will always be unreliable. I think you should move this question over at [so] as this is no loner a Wordpress issue

Comment: If *any* of the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience [`browscap.ini`](http://browscap.org/) based checks are not terrible - at least. There is - probably not the only one - an PHP implementation with [browsecap-php](https://github.com/browscap/browscap-php) that can be used for PHP projects and would be suitable for WP projects too. As for a WordPress implementation, there is the plug-in - I know of - [PHP Browser Detection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-browser-detection/), which as far as I can tell does a good job implementing the functionality. Last but not least, I can't give you any numbers on reliability though, so lets just say, seeing the discussion under your question, you have been warned.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea about using the browser detection plugin to mix two themes in one? If the plugin is reliable, is this a reasonable way?

Comment: The problem is that, even if the detection script is working perfectly, it is not 100% reliable, because browser can lie about their identity and there is absolutely nothing you can do about it. I don't exactly know what you mean by mixing themes, generally, either you make your theme show differently for devices based on CSS or if that is not enough you separate your mobile and desktop site, having two themes. You can of course try to add a specific class to e.g. the `body` by mobile/browser detection and style via CSS. But as said this can't 100% reliable - never ever ever... @BrickYang

Comment: Thanks. My question here is if the detection is not a problem（assume it's 100% reliable), dose the code like `if(is_mobile()) {// mobile theme} else {// desktop theme}` is a good solution?(I mean in all template files do check the device then output different HTML. This is one theme not two separate themes)

Comment: I use wp_is_mobile() in some cases, and it works. Of course, you'll get some misses, but after digging through lots of GA stats and testing I'm pretty confident, that normal browsers without any tweaks and hacks are pretty reliable in terms of determining them - Safari, Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera, some less popular like Yandex etc, both desktop and mobile. So if you have some responsive CSS + removing unnecessary blocks with wp_is_mobile(), you should be fine in most cases. Some 1-2% of misses is not worth your attention unless you are Amazon store.

Answer (score 0):

Add your CSS rules to a Media Query at the end of your style sheet.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

        // Your CSS Rules
}
```